# QGraphicsTextItem is not updating the score

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I want to build a simple game in pyqt, i want when the enemy collides with the bullet increase the score, I have created a Score class that extends from QGraphicsTextItem, I have created the score text also I have added an increase method. after that I have added this class in my Bullet.py file, because in the Bullet.py collision occurs, also I have added this class in my Window.py file, because I want that text should be in the scene, but when I run the game the score is 0 and after colliding nothing happens, these are my files

Window.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import sys
from Player import Player
from Enemy import Enemy
from Score import Score

class Window(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.create_scene()

        self.show()


    def create_scene(self):
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        # create an item to put in the scene
        player = Player()

        # make rect focusable
        player.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsFocusable)
        player.setFocus()

        # by default QGraphicsRectItem has 0 length and width
        player.setRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

        # add item to the scene
        self.scene.addItem(player)

        # set size of the scene
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600)

        # set the player at the botoom
        player.setPos(self.width() / 2, self.height() - player.rect().height())
        

        #adding the score to the scene
        score = Score()
        self.scene.addItem(score)


        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.spawn)
        self.timer.start(2000)


    def spawn(self):
        enemy = Enemy()
        self.scene.addItem(enemy)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Player.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem
from PyQt6.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from Bullet import MyBullet




class Player(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()



    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
        if (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Left):

            if self.pos().x() > 0:
                self.setPos(self.x() - 10, self.y())

        elif (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Right):
            if (self.pos().x() + 100 < 800):
                self.setPos(self.x() + 10, self.y())


        elif (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Space):
            mybullet = MyBullet()
            mybullet.setPos(self.x(), self.y())
            self.scene().addItem(mybullet)
```

Enemy.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem
from random import randint
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer


class Enemy(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        random_number = randint(10,1000) % 700
        self.setPos(random_number , 0)


        self.setRect(0,0,100,100)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move)
        self.timer.start(50)




    def move(self):
        #move enemy to down
        self.setPos(self.x(), self.y()+5)

        if self.pos().y() + self.rect().height() < 0:
            self.scene().removeItem(self)
            print("Bullet deleted")
```

Bullet.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from Enemy import Enemy
from Score import Score


class MyBullet(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.setRect(0, 0, 10, 50)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move)
        self.timer.start(50)


    def move(self):
        # This is the place for the collision
        colliding = self.collidingItems()
        for item in colliding:
            if isinstance(item, Enemy):

                # increase the score
                score = Score()
                score.increase()

                self.scene().removeItem(item)
                self.scene().removeItem(self)

        self.setPos(self.x(), self.y() - 10)

        if self.pos().y() + self.rect().height() < 0:
            self.scene().removeItem(self)
            print("Bullet deleted")
```

And this is my Score.py file

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsTextItem
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont

class Score(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.score = 0
       # draw the text
       self.setPlainText("Score : " + str(self.score))
       self.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.GlobalColor.red)
       self.setFont(QFont("Sanserif", 18))


    def increase(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.setPlainText(str(self.score))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a `score` item every time the collision is detected, but that item is not added to the scene, so it gets deleted at the end of `move`, making it useless; but, even if you *did* add that item to the scene, it would be pointless, since a `score` item already exists on the scene, but you didn't keep a persistent reference to it, so you cannot call it's `increase` method.

So, three changes are required:

1. find a way to communicate *to* the scene that a collision happened and the score has to increase; the correct way to do so would be through a signal, but since basic QGraphicsItems do not inherit from QObject, you cannot create a signal for them, so you can use a class that acts as a "signal proxy";

```
class BulletSignals(QObject):
    enemyHit = pyqtSignal()

class MyBullet(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.proxy = BulletSignals()
        self.enemyHit = self.proxy.enemyHit
        # ...

    def move(self):
        colliding = self.collidingItems()
        isHit = False
        for item in colliding:
            if isinstance(item, Enemy):
                self.scene().removeItem(item)
                isHit = True
        if isHit:
            self.scene().removeItem(self)
            self.enemyHit.emit()

        else:
            self.setY(self.y() - 10)

            if self.pos().y() + self.rect().height() < 0:
                self.scene().removeItem(self)
            print("Bullet deleted")
```

2. connect the signal of the bullet; this requires a small but important change in the logic, and that's because a better and more correct OOP implementation would make the scene's responsibility (or, better, the "main controller") to add the bullet; so, we will add a signal proxy to the player too;

```
class PlayerSignals(QObject):
    fire = pyqtSignal(QPointF)

class Player(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.proxy = PlayerSignal()
        self.fire = self.proxy.fire

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
        if (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Left):
            if self.pos().x() > 0:
                self.setX(max(0, self.x() - 10))

        elif (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Right):
            if (self.pos().x() + 10 < 800):
                self.setX(min(800, self.x() + 10))

        elif (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Space):
            self.fire.emit(self.pos()
```

3. make both `score` and `player` instance members, and connect the signals when required:

```
class Window(QGraphicsView):
    # ...
    def create_scene(self):
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        # create an item to put in the scene
        self.player = Player()
        self.player.fire.connect(self.fire)

        # ...
        self.score = Score()
        self.scene.addItem(self.score)
        # ...

    def fire(self, pos):
        bullet = MyBullet()
        bullet.setPos(pos)
        self.scene.addItem(bullet)
        bullet.enemyHit.connect(self.score.increase)
```

Note that:

1. I changed some small things (most notably, if you only need to move on a single axis, just use `setX()` or `setY()`)
2. as much as it should be the scene/controller responsibility to add items, it should also be to remove them; I didn't change that to avoid complicating things, but remember that an item should be removed only by the scene or one of its ancestors; also, you should not try to remove an item more than once;
3. a timer that could potentially remove an item should be used with care, as the result is that sometimes `move` will be called right after the item has been removed from the scene, which could raise an exception (since `self.scene()` would return `None`); the following change would fix this:

```
class Enemy(QGraphicsRectItem):
    # ...
    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemSceneChange:
            if value:
                self.timer.start(50)
            else:
                self.timer.stop()
        return super().itemChange(change, value)
```

the same obviously is required for MyBullet too, and you should remove `self.timer.start(50)` from both the `__init__` of those classes;

Finally, while the scene of a view is generally always the same during the lifespan of the program, that's not always true; [`scene()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#scene) is an *existing* dynamic function of QGraphicsView, so you should not overwrite it with `self.scene`.